# Stanford Dependency Parser - How to get phrase vectors?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

In the [DependencyParser.java repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/nndep/DependencyParser.java), I can see it’s using recursive neural networks.
And from the open lecture (http://cs224d.stanford.edu), I learned that these networks calculate phrase vectors at each node of the parse tree.

I'm trying to make the Parser to output phrase vectors so that I can plot them on the 2-d plane but so far I haven't figured it out. - Can someone please point me to the java object and line numbers where they are calculated? (I suspect that they would be in line 765~)

```
 private void setupClassifierForTraining(List<CoreMap> trainSents, List<DependencyTree> trainTrees, String embedFile, String preModel) {
    double[][] E = new double[knownWords.size() + knownPos.size() + knownLabels.size()][config.embeddingSize];
    double[][] W1 = new double[config.hiddenSize][config.embeddingSize * config.numTokens];
    double[] b1 = new double[config.hiddenSize];
    double[][] W2 = new double[system.numTransitions()][config.hiddenSize];
```

And if this is not the correct place to be looking for phrase vectors, I'd really appreciate it if you could point me to the code in the [CoreNLP project](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) I should be looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which lecture are you referring to?

This paper describes the neural network dependency parser we distribute:

http://cs.stanford.edu/people/danqi/papers/emnlp2014.pdf

I don't believe it creates phrase embeddings ; it creates embeddings for words, part-of-speech tags, and for dependency labels.

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting on Saturday night! He mentions it here (4' 45'') : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJHvaGU9SW8&index=9&list=PL1qFoj7_pnROfWSqkVKwU3FFtViIdYG8Y

Comment: In the plot at 4:55 in that video, you can see he plots the sentence "the country of my birth" along with "Germany" and "France". This is the lecture on recursive neural networks. He then goes on to describe how the approach gives us a parse structure as well as phrase embeddings. Is that approach implemented in any of the programs in Core-NLP?

Comment: I believe you want to look at this package: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.dvparser

Comment: This is some documentation: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#rnn